# LSTM using "return_sequences=False" return wrong shape dimention [nb_input, nb_neurones] in lieu of [nb_neurones]

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, lstm

I use this code to pass my data inside a LSTM layer,
input 1 and 2: x1, x2

```
this is how I setup my inputs

x1= tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X))
x2= tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Xphysio))
output = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((y))
combined_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip(((inputs_hydro, inputs_static), output))
input_dataset = combined_dataset.batch(batch_size_by_file)
```

and the simple exemple model

```
y = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=False, stateful=False)(input_dataset[0])

merge_2_input = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([y, input_dataset[1])

output = tf.keras.layers.dense(100)(merge_2_input )
```

my X data are shape [nb_sample, 10, 3]
Why the LSTM layer using "return_sequences=False" return me an output of shape [10,100] in lieu of [100]??

see error log:

```
A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(10, 100), (256, 17)]

Call arguments received by layer "feed_back" "                 f"(type FeedBack):
  • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(256, 10, 3), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(256, 17), dtype=float32)')
  • training=True
```

Comment: @GoldenLion No, only one LSTM layer, I did the modification to the question and add all layers.

Comment: @GoldenLion I post how my outputs are build juste in case

Comment: my error, dense(1), only forecasting one value